# Record Voice Message After Whisper Call (when not answered)

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml, voicemail

Please see picture below of what I currently have.

Welcome Message > Menu Options (English, Spanish and Portuguese) > Whisper Call.

I set up 3 whisper calls sets (whisper and forwarding, per language) in TwiML Bin. The whispers are working well for each language.

I am having an issue though when the whisper call is rejected or not answered. The call is being sent to the voicemail of the phone number in the whisper setup (my cellphone) not on the voicemail function of Twilio.

Can anyone shed some light on how to fix it, so the voice message records in Twilio?

[image]

Comment: Can you share the TwiML of your whisper?